# What does $(ls *.txt) do?

Tags: command-line, bash

In a unix terminal, if I do:

```
egrep "Stuff" $(ls *.txt)
```

The result is obvious. But what does

`$(ls *.txt)` do on its own? I see I can replicate the effect by

```
egrep "Stuff" *.txt
```

So what is `$(ls *.txt)`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984958/what-does-it-mean-in-shell-when-we-put-a-command-inside-dollar-sign-and-parenthe

Comment: See also [Useless use of `ls *`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#ls)

Comment: Also [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/).

Comment: You'd only do this if you're writing an obfuscated shell script that supports getting extra `grep` options from the *names* of files that end in `.txt`.  Maybe with `IFS=$'\n'` so you could avoid word-splitting filenames with whitespace other than newline.  This is obviously not what anyone wants in normal circumstances; I'm just trying to imagine an actual use-case for what is normally a bad/wrong way to do something.

Comment: Fun fact: [GNU `ls` has a `--quoting-style=shell-always`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) option which might make this safe (but still worse than just `*.txt`).  Arch Linux builds `ls` with quoting enabled by default when the output is a terminal, I guess for copy/pasting purposes.

Answer (score 28):

*"what does `$(ls *.txt)` do"*

#### Short answer

`$(ls *.txt)` gathers a list of file names and **then mangles them**.  Do **not** use this.

#### Longer answer

- `ls` is intended for human-readable output.  As one of ls's maintainers [wrote](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2014-02/msg00005.html) in response to why `ls` would not offer a `--null` option:

  > If we were to do this then this is the interface we would use. However
  >   **`ls` is really a tool for direct consumption by a human**, and in that
  >   case further processing is less useful. For futher processing, `find`(1)
  >   is more suited. [emphasis added]

  In other words, use of `ls` for anything other than display to humans is just not supported.  `ls` maintainers, for example, recently changed the default output format to something they though more human-friendly [without warning](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258679/why-is-ls-suddenly-wrapping-items-with-spaces-in-single-quotes).  So, follow their advice: if you are going to do further processing of file names, use `find` instead of `ls`.
- `$(...)` is command substitution.  One consequence of using command substitution is that trailing newline characters are removed.  If the last file name in the list happens to contain trailing newlines, they will be removed.
- Since `$(...)` is not double-quoted, the text it produces will be subject to:

  - *Word splitting*
  - *Pathname expansion*

  The result of both of these is further mangling of the file names.
- not to mention the issues with file names starting with `-` because of the missing `--` (for both `ls` and `egrep` as Ubuntu's `egrep` being the GNU implementation accepts options even after non-option arguments unless `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment).
- also, if any of those `txt` files were of type *directory*, `ls` would list their *content* instead of themselves.
- and if there's no `txt` files, the output of `ls` will be empty (though you'll see an error about a missing `*.txt` file) and as `egrep` will receive no file argument, it will look for *Stuff* in its standard input (and seemingly hang).

#### Example

Let's create 4 files containing `Stuff` in our directory:

```
$ echo Stuff | tee file1 file2 'a b c.txt' 'f* .txt'
Stuff
$ ls -Q
"a b c.txt"  "file1"  "file2"  "f* .txt"
```

Now, let's run the egrep command:

```
$ egrep "Stuff" $(ls *.txt)
grep: a: No such file or directory
grep: b: No such file or directory
grep: c.txt: No such file or directory
file1:Stuff
file2:Stuff
f* .txt:Stuff
grep: .txt: No such file or directory
```

Observe that we get 4 error messages about nonexistent files.  This is due to *word splitting*.  The result also shows matches with two files, `file1` and `file2` that should not have been searched because they don't end with `.txt`.  This is because of _pathname expansion`.

The correctly written command produces two successful matches and no errors:

```
$ egrep -- "Stuff" *.txt
a b c.txt:Stuff
f* .txt:Stuff
```

#### Recommended solution

Use:

```
egrep -- "Stuff" *.txt
```

or POSIXly:

```
grep -E -- "Stuff" *.txt
```

or:

```
grep -E -e Stuff -- *.txt
```

This will work with any file name and has none of the limitations of the `ls` approach.

Comment: pretty clear approach

Comment: Your first point about alteration of file names is only true when the output goes to a terminal, not when it goes to a pipe like in this case.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Interesting.  I'm seeing that also.  Thanks.  I just updated the answer to replace that statement with a quote from one of the ls maintainers stating that `ls` should not be used for anything other than human consumption.

Answer (score 6):

The `$( )` runs the command `ls *.txt` and returns the `STDOUT` of the command.

What this particular usage is, is a newbie programming mistake on at least three levels:

1. `egrep 'Stuff' *.txt` works, like you said, except for files named something like `A File.txt`
2. Using `ls` output for program input is unwise. See [reasons](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)
3. `$( ls *.txt)` mishandles filenames with spaces and other funny characters. `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 egrep 'Stuff'` is a more bullet-resistant way.

A contrived example of shell glob expansion/confusion, in response to @8bittree is:

```
$ /bin/ls -l -b
total 36
-rw------- 1 w3 walt 2 Aug 11 13:41 A\ \\012\ File.txt
-rw------- 1 w3 walt 2 Aug 11 13:42 A\ \n\ File.txt
-rw------- 1 w3 walt 2 Aug 11 13:40 A\ File.txt

$ grep "STUFF" $(ls *.txt)
grep: A: No such file or directory
grep: \012: No such file or directory
grep: File.txt: No such file or directory
grep: A: No such file or directory
grep: File.txt: No such file or directory
grep: A: No such file or directory
grep: File.txt: No such file or directory

$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 egrep 'Stuff'

$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 egrep '1'
./A File.txt:1
```

Comment: Also, using `find`'s `-exec` action rather than `-print0`+`xargs -0` would be more efficient, although I'll concede its syntax is bothersome. In this case it would be `find [...] -exec egrep 'Stuff' {} \;` or `find [...] -exec egrep 'Stuff' {} +` ; in the second case `grep` handles multiple files at once, so the result will be prefixed by the file path (which could be disabled with `grep`'s `-h` flag)

Comment: @Aaron I had never seen the "{} +" syntax of find, very interesting.  Using "-exec egrep 'Stuff' {} \;" without the + would actually be less efficient since it would fork off a new grep process for every file.  Also, I usually run the grep with an additional file of /dev/null so I will get file names listed in the output even if only 1 file ends up in the grep command.  e.g. find ... -print0 | xargs -0 egrep 'Stuff' /dev/null

Comment: @Aner concerning the efficiency of `{} \;` you're right. Also, `grep`'s `-H` flag is shorter to type than `/dev/null` ;) Always good to re-read the command's `--help` (if not its man) from time to time, such goodies come into existence every few versions.

Comment: `find -print0 | xargs` is no more robust than `grep -E *txt`. Globs are absolutely safe with any file name you throw at them. Your `find` example will also work, yes, but it has no benefit whatsoever over the glob; it's just a *lot* more complex.

Comment: Filenames are allowed to contain ANY character, except slash("`/`") or `NUL` (`0x00`). `find ... -print0` is the only safe way to handle arbitrary filenames. Shell globs get confused by spaces. Another advantage of `find` is dealing with long pathnames.

Comment: "Shell globs get confused by spaces" - Evidence please. My tests of matching `A File.txt` with `*.txt` work just fine. And the [Bash manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc13) explicitly states that filename pattern expansion happens after word splitting: "**Pathname Expansion:** After word splitting, [...]  bash  scans each  word  for the characters *, ?, and [.  If one of these characters appears, then the word is regarded as a pattern, and replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of file names matching the pattern."

Comment: @8bittree see modified answer.

Comment: Um, your example does a whole lot more than just globbing. Using `$()` and `ls` on the glob are causing the problems, not the glob itself. Try `grep "STUFF" *.txt`.

Comment: That is not an example of a glob being confused by spaces, that's just a bad example of parsing ls. Using globs means using a glob pattern, not the results of running `ls` on that glob pattern. As 8bittree pointed out, `grep STUFF  *txt` will work fine, as will `for i in *txt; do grep STUFF "$i"; done`. There is no file name that will make a glob choke. That's what they're designed for.

Comment: @Aaron "Also, using find's `-exec` action rather than `-print0|xargs -0` would be more efficient,"? 1 process creation per file with `-exec`? `xargs` runs the command once for every `131072` bytes of filenames. See `xargs --show-limits`. How many files (max)  have you processed coming out of `find` vs with `-exec`? I'm over 100000.

Comment: @terdon In the old days, when `sh` was first designed, " " wasn't used in filenames. Further development, standardization, etc expanded the definition of what could be in a filename to include everything except `/` and `NUL` (0x00). Filenames can include spaces. Splitting arguments on spaces will misparse these filenames. `*.txt` = `"A \012 File.txt A\n 
 File.txt A File.txt"` How will "parsing ls" help? See "reasons" above.

Comment: @waltinator `find`'s `-exec` has two terminators: `;` and `+`. `;` calls the exec action with one file at a time. `+` batches the files together, similarly to `xargs`, but without the need to set up a pipe and an extra process. Also, as I have pointed out multiple times **word splitting happens before filename globbing**. Parsing `ls` will not help. No one has claimed that it will. And I will note that your example shows globbing working just fine because `grep`, not `ls` complained, meaning you only had broken file names *after* mangling them with ls and a subshell.

Answer (score 3):

Wow, for a moment I thought you were wondering about `` `$(ls *.txt)` `` (with `$(..)` plus backquotes)

As the question has already been answered, I will just warn you about one thing. Here is a sequence of commands to show you why it can be dangerous:

- `set -x`
  To see what is executed
- `touch 'rm -f *.txt'`
  Create a text file named 'rm -f *.txt', I use simple quotes here so Bash won't expand the wildcard and spaces.
- `` `$(ls *.txt)` ``
  Here is the tricky part. The command `ls *.txt` will be run, then redirect the result to STDOUT. This result, `rm -f *.txt` will be now executed because of the backquotes.
  So, rm will remove every text files, in our case the file `rm -f *.txt`

I hope you understand, - as a demonstration just run the previous commands in an empty directory, so you won't break anything.

Comment: Since that was added by another user, and since ` ``...`` ` has no effects in question titles, I have removed the superfluous backticks.

Comment: Yep, you're right, title has changed  ! Anyway, I think this won't hurt anyone to understand what double command execution can do.

Answer (score 2):

```
$( ... )
```

Is a command substitution, it assigns the output of one or more commands as an input to another command. The old syntax is: `` ` ... ` ``.

The different is that your commands will get run in different shells:

```
echo $BASHPID $( echo $BASHPID )
5718 7138
```

It actually invokes a subshell:

```
echo $BASH_SUBSHELL $( echo $BASH_SUBSHELL )
0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to have little utility in the real world but,

A better way to get a usable result is:

```
echo $(ls *.txt)
```

Or just

```
ls *.txt
```

This will list all files with a .txt extension.  To find text files that contain a particular string,

```
egrep -l "Stuff" *.txt
```

For more information on search tools, do a

```
man egrep
```

Comment: How is `echo $(ls *.txt)` more _usable_ than say `echo *.txt`. It's definitely a lot less reliable because most of the points listed in John's answer also apply there. Note that `ls *.txt` doesn't _list all files with a .txt extension_. You'd need `ls -d -- *.txt` for that.